# How to get Netbeans to increment version / build number of .WAR in Maven based project?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, deployment

I'm working on a Maven based web project in Netbeans. The problem is, each time I build the app, it has the same version number in the war, e.g 'myProject-0.0.1.war`. When I deploy it to Amazon EBS I have to manually type in a new version label since it just puts in the name of the war as the version label.

Is there a way to get Netbeans to use an incrementing version number with each build, e.g 0.0.1, 0.0.2, or even just 'myproject-build1000.war', 'myproject-build10001.war' etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although NetBeans is a very Maven-friendly application, the version numbers are very much a Maven thing - NetBeans doesn't have much to do with them.

There does appear to be a solution here:

https://code.google.com/p/autoincrement-versions-maven-plugin/

I've not tried it, but it seems to do what you want.

More generally, to really understand the reasoning behind version numbers in Maven, check out the maven release plugin. On a more practical note, the maven versions plugin is a very useful tool for modifying version numbers in poms.